# Not able to create a Kafka topic using Confluent while the broker is running in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I am getting an error while trying to create a topic in the container.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 29093:29093
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://:29093,INTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://172.23.0.3:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

After running the docker container I am running the following Python code on my local machine which should connect to the Kafka broker in the container:

```
def create_kafka_topic(bootstrap_servers, topic_name, num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1):
    # Configure the admin client with the bootstrap servers
    admin_client = AdminClient({'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers})

    # Create a NewTopic object with topic configuration
    new_topic = NewTopic(topic_name, num_partitions=num_partitions, replication_factor=replication_factor)

    # Create the topic
    admin_client.create_topics([new_topic])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Configure your Kafka broker address here
    bootstrap_servers = "localhost:29092"

    # Topic details
    topic_name = config.TOPIC
    num_partitions = config.NUM_PARTITIONS
    replication_factor = 1
    
    # Create the Kafka topic for transactions
    create_kafka_topic(bootstrap_servers, topic_name_transactions, num_partitions, replication_factor)
```

But running the above code is giving the following output:

`%6|1691170181.360|BGQUEUE|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:background]: Purging 1 unserved events from background queue`

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure it out.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your logs say `rdkafka#producer`, but you're using an AdminClient? That doesn't seem right. Where did you create a producer? Also, the wurstmeister Kafka image allows you to create topics direct from environment variables. There's no reason to use Confluent images for confluent libraries

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks a lot for your time in reading my question, but I've figured out and fixed the problem. The issue was with the connection being made to the broker in the container from my localhost -- creating an AdminClient object takes time so I added a `time.sleep(10)` and that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:- I've figured out the issue I'm facing!
The `docker-compose.yml` file is alright as it is, the problem was with the Python file. I tried running each line separately in an interactive Python shell and it worked, so the problem was the time it was taking to create the `AdminClient` object. So, adding a time.sleep(10) right after creating the object is one solution. A better solution would be to create a function that checks if the AdminClient has been created by sending constant requests, something like this which is more robust -

```
def wait_for_admin_client(admin_client):
    # Wait until the admin client is connected to the Kafka cluster
    while True:
        metadata = admin_client.list_topics(timeout=5)
        if metadata is not None:
            break
        admin_client.poll(0.1)
```

And then this -

```
def create_kafka_topic(broker_name, topic_names, num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1):
    # Configure the admin client with the bootstrap servers
    admin_client = AdminClient({
        'bootstrap.servers': broker_name
    })

    # time.sleep(15)
    wait_for_admin_client(admin_client)
    # ... rest remains the same
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: An even better solution IMO would be adding a healthcheck and wait_for, service-healthy definition to run a new container in your Compose file that creates topics